# not returning geofire data In firebase cloud functions javaScript properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, geofire

```
let geolocationRef = db.ref("geolocations/");

var lat = data.lat;
var lon = data.lon;
var area = data.area;
var reqFacilities = data.facilities || [];
var geoFire = new GeoFire(geolocationRef);
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: [parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lon)],
    radius: parseFloat(area) // the minimum radius that will return
});

var hotelDataArray = [];
geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
  let adsRef = db.ref("ads/" + key);
    adsRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.val().facilities !== undefined) {
            let facilityArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val().facilities);
            if (reqFacilities.every(val => facilityArray.includes(val))) {
      console.log("Pushed") 
                 hotelDataArray.push({key: key, distance: distance.toFixed(2), data :snapshot.val()});
            }
        }
    })

});
console.log(hotelDataArray,"last")
```

return {hotelDataArray};

});

This is my geofire code to get nearest hotels with given facilities 
but it not returning data properly 
the console print like

- [ ] last
- pushed
- pushed

Returning nil value

I need to sort hotels with facilities, how to sort it properly
help me please